# Is MariaDB usable in production with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mariadb

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB

> MariaDB is a community-developed branch of the MySQL database, the
>   impetus being the community maintenance of its free status under the
>   GNU GPL, as opposed to any uncertainty of MySQL license status under
>   its current ownership by Oracle. The contributors are required to
>   share their copyright with Monty Program AB.

The page goes on to say that MariaDB 5.5 is binary-compatible with the MySQL of the same version and adds a couple of database engines of its own to choose from.

[I also read](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTI4MDY) that Fedora 19 is going to remove MySQL packages in favor of MariaDB.

So the question is, is Ruby on Rails 3+ MariaDB compatible? Are there any future plans to integrate MariaDB features as they start to deviate from MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Red Hat, Debian, Fedora, OpenSuse, Slackware, and even Wikipedia moved (or are moving) to MariaDB. This means it is stable. Also, MariaDB (and Percona Server) seems to fix security issues much faster than Oracle.

Since MariaDB is compatible with MySQL, all APIs are compatible, including Ruby on Rails API.
(Well, MariaDB 10.0 is not totally compatible with MySQL 5.6, but the incompatibilities are not at API-level!)

Comment: That "compatible, well incompatible but don't worry" response style is what we've been getting since The Great Divorce. It's not wholly reassuring! And not only about the present state: when you ask about the future, the hand-jive gets positively euphoric. It'd be nice if someone could report they've already tried it ...

Comment: The [Rails Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rubyonrails-talk/mariadb) shows some users, and my brief scan didn't turn up any DB-related issues.

Comment: @hackr, advanced users need to test before upgrading the production db server. When you upgrade MySQL 5.5 to 5.6, there is a chance you will have problems with bugs or new optimizer features. When you upgrade MySQL 5.6 to MariaDB 10.0, it is the same. If you survived to the traps of 5.6 metadata locks, why are you afraid of MariaDB? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Mariadb with any compatible MySQL client. I am using MySQL .NET connector and it just work.